# how to get a form id unique in a foreach

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user)
{
   //some php code here to define variables
   <a href="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to; ?>" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
      <?php echo $uniqueCode1;?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2;?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3;?>
   </a>      
   <form id="message_area_<?php echo $id_to; ?>" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to; ?>"> 
       <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
       <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
       <input type='hidden' name='mid' id='message_id' value=""></input>
   </form>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

then i have:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function showMessageArea(link)
{
  document.getElementById('message_id').value = this.id;
  var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+this.id);
  message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
  link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
  message_area.style.display="block";
}
```

my pagesource shows this: note that form id is unique

```
<a href="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=36" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" > 
    KUZELJA<span class="pink_text">000</span>RC
</a>      
<form id="message_area_36" style="display:none"  method="post" action="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=36"> 
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> 
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input> 
   <input type='hidden' name='mid' id='message_id' value=""></input> 
</form> 
<a href="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=38" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" > 
   ALANZIM<span class="pink_text">000</span>RC 
</a>      
<form id="message_area_38" style="display:none"  method="post" action="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=38"> 
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> 
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input> 
   <input type='hidden' name='mid' id='message_id' value=""></input> 
</form>
```

the problem NOW is: in my JS this.id is undefined????? THUS NOT showing my textarea and sumbit button
how can i get var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+this.id) unique???
i also tried to split.link("=")[1] to get id and concatenate it with message_area_
but it is not working
link is also unique, http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=36 where id will be the id of the uniquecode link i clicked on

PLEASE i need help?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1) add `id="<?php echo $to_id; ?>"` to your `<a>` tags, OR

2) better pass the id as javascript function parameter:

```
<a ... onclick="showMessageArea(this, '<?php echo $to_id; ?>'); return false;">
```

and then your javascript function should look like this

```
function showMessageArea(link, id)
{
    document.getElementById('message_id').value = id;
    var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+id);
    ....
}
```

Comment: thank you im getting the id correct but still my var message_area is not unique and thus my actual message area and submit button is not showing

Comment: Well, I don't see why don't you move that form outside of the `foreach` loop - it is causing you problems now, because again you have inputs now with the non-unique id `message_id`. Please move the form outside of loop. And remove `?id=<?php echo $id_to; ?>` from the form action - you are already using and setting `<input name="id" ... />` which is doing the same thing (but only in a correct way)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in the php code:

```
onclick="showMessageArea('<?php echo $id_to; ?>'); return false;"
```

Then you can get the message area by:

```
var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+link);
```

Comment: original `this`/`link` parameter is needed in the further DOM manipulations, so you can't disregard it this easy.